# how can I set custom marker icon with markers cluster in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have try to use mapView() function and only when I click on the marker, that choose marker will change to custom marker icon. How can I change the default marker (WITH CLUSTERING).

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {

        let poiItem = marker.userData as? POIItem
        marker.title = poiItem?.devname
        marker.snippet = poiItem?.address
        marker.icon = UIImage(named: "runcar1")
        return false
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 : GO to Poitem class

Add one more element to that class

```
 let marker = GMSMarker()
```

add that in init method too

and then simple called

```
 let myitem = POitem() 
 myitem.marker = GMSMarker(latitude:0,longitude:0)
 self.map.add(myitem)
```